# Why am I getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am running this code to find the sum of even numbers.
here is my code.

```py
from functools import reduce

liste = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def cift_mi(a):
    if (a % 2 == 0):
        return True
    return False

ciftler = (list(filter(cift_mi,liste)))

def toplama(a,b):
    return a + b

sonuc=(list(reduce(toplama,list(ciftler))))

print(sonuc)
```

When I run the code I receive this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The TypeError is being raised by `sonuc=(list(reduce(...)))`. The call to `reduce` produces an `int`, so you're attempting to call `list(<some int>)`. `list` expects its argument to be an iterable, which ints are not, hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure this out, look at what line the error occurs on:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    sonuc=(list(reduce(toplama,list(ciftler))))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

It shows the line where the error occurs, but there are several things happening on that line, so we can break it up into separate parts:

```
ciftler_list = list(ciftler)
reduced_value = reduce(toplama, ciftler_list)
sonuc = list(reduced_value)
```

And now the error changes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    sonuc = list(reduced_value)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The error is saying that `list` is trying to iterate a value, but that value is an int, so it can't. That means `reduced_value` must be an int. So, the `reduce` function must be returning an int.

And this makes sense, because your reduce function `toplama` is returning `a + b`, so `reduce` is going to return the sum of all the values in `ciftler`. Its return value is an int, not a list, so you can't call `list()` on it.

You probably want the assignment to look like this:

```
# ciftler is already a list, don't need to call list() again
sonuc = reduce(toplama, ciftler)
```